# Write a Python function that accepts a string and calculate the number of upper case letters and lower case letters

Tags: python

Question:
Write a Python function that accepts a string and calculate the number of upper case letters and lower case letters.
Sample String : 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
Expected Output : 
No. of Upper case characters : 4
No. of Lower case Characters : 33

function:

```
def up_low(s):
  for a in s:
    u = u.count(a.isupper())
    l = l.count(a.islowwer())
  print(u, l)
```

why this one doesn't work?

Comment: What about this doesn't work? Is it an error, or is it returning unexpected results? Also please fix your indentation - the code that is currently posted will fail with IndentationError because the contents of the for loop is not indented.

Comment: Your spacing might be off (since in python spacing matters). If that&#39;s your exact code block, tab over everything in the for loop 

Adding on to this, I'm not sure if isupper and islower get the count of the upper case and lower case letters, you may need to iterate each char in the word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use List comprehensions and sum function to get the total number of upper and lower case letters.

```
def up_low(s):      
    u = sum(1 for i in s if i.isupper())
    l = sum(1 for i in s if i.islower())
    print( "No. of Upper case characters : %s,No. of Lower case characters : %s" % (u,l))

up_low("Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?")
```

Output:
    No. of Upper case characters : 4,No. of Lower case characters : 33

Comment: `u = sum(i.isupper() for i in s)` etc.

Comment: Got the following error: ```SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal```.  Why would that be? @Bharath

Answer (score 2):

You are understanding wrong the count function, count, first of all, is a string functrion, and as parameter take a string, instead of doing this, you can simply do:

```
def up_low(string):
  uppers = 0
  lowers = 0
  for char in string:
    if char.islower():
      lowers += 1
    elif char.isupper():
      uppers +=1
    else: #I added an extra case for the rest of the chars that aren't lower non upper
      pass
  return(uppers, lowers)

print(up_low('Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'))
```

> 4 33

Comment: Apart from the too-short variable names - this is a good solution and will run quite fast

Comment: @JohnLaRooy thanks so much for the feedback, means a lot to me

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I made the edit according your suggestions :)

Comment: Thanks exact match with what I attempted.

Answer (score 1):

If people are posting code...

```
def up_low(s):
    up = filter(str.isupper, s)
    low = filter(str.islower, s)
    return len(up), len(low)
```

In Python 3, each filter will need to be converted into a list or thrown into a `sum(1 for _ in ...)` expression:

```
def up_low(s):
    counter = lambda f: sum(1 for c in s if f(c))
    return counter(str.upper), counter(str.lower)
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()` if i run this

Comment: @JohnLaRooy If you want this to work in Py3, you'll need to cast it to a `list`.

Comment: @ChristianDean, or you can use `map` instead of `filter` and `sum` instead of `len`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Yes, those are also valid options. Though I'm not sure how efficient each one would be...

Comment: @ChristianDean, map+sum is twice as fast as the python3 version in this answer for the string `"Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?"`. But speed isn't everything...

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

> why this one doesn't work?

Along with having syntax errors and run-time errors, you code's logic is quite a ways off. You are actual not doing what the question asked. You seem to be trying to count the number of uppercase characters in a single character. That's incorrect.

Let's look back over the question to implement this correctly:

> Write a Python function **that accepts a string and calculate the number of upper case letters and lower case letters**. Sample String : `'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'` Expected Output : No. of Upper case characters : `4` No. of Lower case Characters : `33`.

Ok, so we have a clear definition of our problem. Given a single string, count the number of lower case characters the string contains, and uppercase characters the string contains. Let's start writing our function.

First we should define a function:

```
def count_upper_and_lower(string):
```

I know we'll need two variables; How? Because we need one to count the uppercase letters, and one to count the lowercase letters. So let's initialize those:

```
def count_upper_lower(string):
    lowercase_letter_count = 0
    uppercase_letter_count = 0
```

Now what do we need?  Well the problem says to ***count each letter in the string***. It sounds like we need to iterate over each character in the string. So we should use a `for` loop:

```
def count_upper_lower(string):
    lowercase_letter_count = 0
    uppercase_letter_count = 0

    for letter in string:
```

OK, so what logic do we need in our for loop? Well we need to first check if a letter is upper case. If it is, we need to increment `uppercase_letter_count`. If not, we'll then test if the character is lowercase. If so, we'll increment `lowercase_letter_count`. Otherwise, we'll do nothing. Here is what that would look like in code:

```
if letter.isupper():
    uppercase_letter_count += 1
elif letter.islower():
    lowercase_letter_count += 1
```

Let's add that to our `for` loop:

```
def count_upper_lower(string):
    lowercase_letter_count = 0
    uppercase_letter_count = 0

    for letter in string:
        if letter.isupper():
            uppercase_letter_count += 1
        elif letter.islower():
            lowercase_letter_count += 1
```

And were done. All that's left to do is to print the values at the end of the function:

```
def count_upper_lower(string):
    lowercase_letter_count = 0
    uppercase_letter_count = 0

    for letter in string:
        if letter.isupper():
            uppercase_letter_count += 1
        elif letter.islower():
            lowercase_letter_count += 1

    print uppercase_letter_count, lowercase_letter_count
```

### Demo

```
def count_upper_lower(string):
    lowercase_letter_count = 0
    uppercase_letter_count = 0

    for letter in string:
        if letter.isupper():
            uppercase_letter_count += 1
        elif letter.islower():
            lowercase_letter_count += 1

    print uppercase_letter_count, lowercase_letter_count


count_upper_lower("Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?")
# Output: 4 33
count_upper_lower("The FAT Cat Moaned AlL day!")
# Output: 8 13
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but for the sake of completeness:

```
import string

def up_low(s):
    return (sum(map(s.count, string.ascii_uppercase)),
            sum(map(s.count, string.ascii_lowercase)))
```

And to test it:

```
u, l = up_low('Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?')
print("No. of Upper case characters : {}\nNo. of Lower case Characters : {}".format(u, l))
```

Which gives:

```
No. of Upper case characters : 4
No. of Lower case Characters : 33
```

A manual loop & count is probably faster, tho.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest approach for a beginner.

```
def up_low(s):
    a=list(s)       
    u=[]
    l=[]
    for x in a:
        if x.isupper():
            u.append(x)
        elif x.islower():
            l.append(x)
        else:
            pass  
    return u, l

u, l = up_low(s)        
print(f'No. of Upper case characters: {len(u)}')
print(f'No. of Lower case Characters: {len(l)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple

```py
def up_low(s):
    c_upper = 0
    c_lower = 0
    for letters in s:
        if letters.isupper():
            c_upper += 1
        elif letters.islower():
            c_lower += 1
        else:
            pass
    print("Total characters :",len(s.replace(" ", "")),"\nNo. of Upper case characters :",c_upper, "\nNo. of Lower case Characters :",c_lower)
```

INPUT

```py
mystring = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
up_low(mystring)
```

OUTPUT

```
Total characters : 40 
No. of Upper case characters : 4 
No. of Lower case Characters : 33
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def up_low(s):
    u, l = [], []
    for a in s:
        if a.isupper():
            u.append(a)
        else:
            l.append(a)
    print(len(u), len(l))
```

Comment: If you just want to count, I wouldn't recommend storing in a list to just print the length when incrementing a counter does the job.